# Simple convergence and uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Evaluate the simple convergence and uniform convergence over the interval $(0, \infty)$ for the sequence of functions:

For $n \geq 0$ and $\forall x \in (0, \infty),~~f_n(x) = \tan^{-1}\bigl( \frac{n+x}{1+nx} \bigr)$.

We have $f_n(0) = \tan^{-1}(n)$ which converges to $\pi/2$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, so I can say that the sequence converges but what the convergence uniformly?

Thanks to the comment below, it seems that I can't consider $f_n(0)$. Consequently, can I use inequalities?

i.e to say $|f_n(x)| \le\frac\pi2\ $  and so converges ?

Comment: You wrote $f_n(0)$ but $f_n$ is not defined at $0.$

Comment: @zhw Yes you are right. So, I need to consider the $\sup$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have  $f_n(x) \to f(x) = \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ pointwise for $x \in (0,\infty)$.

To examine uniform convergence, consider

$$\begin{align}\sup_{x \in (0,\infty)}|f_n(x) - f(x)| &= \sup_{x \in (0,\infty)}\left| \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{n+x}{1+nx}\right) - \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right| \\ &= \sup_{x \in (0,\infty)}\left| \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{\frac{n+x}{1+nx} - \frac{1}{x}}{1 +\frac{n+x}{1+nx}\frac{1}{x} } \right)\right| \\ &= \sup_{x \in (0,\infty)}\left| \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{x(n+x)- 1 - nx}{x(1+nx) +  n+x} \right)\right| \\ &= \sup_{x \in (0,\infty)}\left| \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{x^2-1}{n(x^2+1) +  2x} \right)\right|  \end{align}$$

Can you find the behavior of the RHS as $n \to \infty$? Recall that the arctangent is an increasing function.

Comment: Great help. Unfortunately, I am not sure about what I found. It is positive for some values of $x$  and negative for the rest and I am not familiar with such cases. I would be grateful if you can give more details

Comment: @Jean:  The arctangent is an increasing odd function.  For $x > 1$ we have $\frac{x^2 - 1}{n(x^2+1) + 2x} < \frac{x^2}{nx^2} = \frac{1}{n}$ and $\tan^{1} \left( \frac{x^2 - 1}{n(x^2+1) + 2x}\right) <\tan^{-1}(1/n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.  For $0 < x \leqslant 1$ we have $\left|\tan^{1} \left( \frac{x^2 - 1}{n(x^2+1) + 2x}\right) \right| = \tan^{1} \left( \frac{1- x^2}{n(x^2+1) + 2x}\right) < \tan^{-1}(1/n) \to 0$.